# Unable to add new host to Apache webserver

Tags: dns, apache2, webserver

I already have two hosts pointing to my machine, and I am trying to add a third "webmail.user.domain.com, but I receive DNS failure lookup. I created a configuration file for "webmail" with the same settings as the other two hosts. My primary zone is this: $ORIGIN user.domain.com.
    @  IN SOA ns.user.domain.com. hostmaster.user.domain.com. (
                                    0       ; serial
                                    1D      ; refresh
                                    1H      ; retry
                                    1W      ; expire
                                    3H )    ; minimum

```
@       IN      NS      ns.user.domain.com.
@       IN      MX      10 mail.user.domain.com.



ns      IN      A       n.n.n.n
mail    IN      A       n.n.n.n
m0      IN      A       n.n.n.n
m1      IN      A       n.n.n.n


www0    IN      CNAME   m0
www1    IN      CNAME   m0
webmail IN      CNAME   m0
```

I guess my question is why does webmail receive a DNS lookup failure even though its pointing to my machine? Do I need to create a zone in named.conf? Any help will greatly be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Unless you are pointed to the DNS server where you are making changes, it can take a while before your changes can be seen depending upon circumstances.

Comment: If all the records are for the same root domain why don't you just use 1 zone file instead of multiples ?